# Selenium - How to get elements correctly on a high-frequency refresh webpage

Tags: java, selenium

There are several high-frequency refresh elements on my target site.

The elements may change text, hide or appear, but all of them are #div.

I need to keep fetching these elements every 1 second so I have:

```
while(true)
{
    List<WebElement> tmp = web.findElements(By);
    for(WebElement ele : tmp)
    {
      System.out.println(ele.getText());
    }   
    Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
```

I'll get exception :

> Element is no longer attached to the DOM

while doing the for loop and it's because the element of the site has been refreshed before I print it.

Is there any solution to solve this? I have tried using try-catch to skip the exception, but I still cannot get all of them. I am thinking that if I could stop the page from refreshing, and restart it after the for loop done. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `findElement` for div which is fixed and use `getText()` to get all the text together..:)

Comment: Or try using `JavascriptExecutor`..

Comment: Thank Saurabh Gaur! I use findElements instead of findElement because I don't know the exact number of div on my target site. And the site is on ASP, I don't know how to use JavascriptExecutor to control them. I don't see any JS function that is seem to refresh page.

Comment: Basically what do you want with the elements?? Do you want their text or something else??

Comment: @AndyCHH, Based on the error message observed, please try keeping some weight before accessing the element like `new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele)`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur
Their text, for example
`<div id = "BLOCK">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
           ...
</div>`
I want the text of all div in the BLOCK, but I don't know how many div in the BLOCK and they would be refreshed (ex: text 1 change into 10,  hide, or disappear)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur
@k.s.Karthik
Thank both of you a lot! I just try `web.findElement(By.id("BLOCK")).getText()` , and I can get the text of all div by this method. Just need to deal with the String by splitting them.

Comment: That's the point I was saying...:)

Comment: You can post it as an answer..that's will really help to other..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur You're right! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
<div id = "BLOCK"> 
   <div>1</div> 
   <div>2</div> 
   ... 
</div>
```

If we want to get the text of all div under BLOCK, we can use

```
web.findElement(By.id("BLOCK")).getText();
```

It will return

```
>     1
>     2
>     ...
```

Then, deal with the String we get by split("\n").

This works on not only `div` but other tags such as `tr, td, p, etc`.